# CE BJT amplifier phase shift

Tags: amplifier, bjt, ltspice, multisim, phase-shift

I built simple CE amplifier in Multisim:

[image]

and make AC analysis, the phase are:

[image]

What is the reverse near 10 kHz? I make the identical circuit in LTSpice but there is no any equal to Multisim on phase output created with LTSpice. What is it? May be it's a difference in behaviour of AC analysis in Multisim in comparing to LTSpice? In Multisim I set v_out/v_in for an output graph but in LTSpice there is no manual settings I found, only ac analysis without output options exists. May be I see any other variable in LTSpice in output graph in comparing to Multisim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the reverse near 10 kHz?

Try rescaling your Y axis to centre it around -180 degrees. There is nothing anomalous if you consider that the transition changes from -180 degrees to +180 degrees. It's just multisim thinking that the lower display boundary is getting a bit too close and rescaling -180 degrees to +180 degrees so it can adequately display the phase change at frequencies higher than 10 kHz.

[image]

Comment: It seems to be rescaling don't changes the display of diagram and it need to keep in mind that this display style is a feature.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are saying.

Comment: Is there any else method to fix that. I other words what I need to do to make the phasor graph looks like in any paper audio magazine?

Comment: i don't use multisim. Maybe ask a new question to get attention from users that do.

Comment: I mark the question with tag "Multisim" and think that it must be enough to call other users, or not?

Comment: @G36 May you help here?

Comment: I can't fully undertand why the -180 and +180 are same? For example if the phase shift was -170 deg on frequency = 10 kHz then the next phase shift will be -170 + 180 = 10 deg on 11 kHz, why it's equal things?

Comment: If you walk around a circular path to halfway you must go through 180 degrees. Does it matter whether you travelled +180 degrees or -180 degrees. You still end up at the same place.

Comment: Yeah, understand, but it seems to be not 180 deg, but it need to travel around 360 deg to go to same point

Comment: If you phase advanced a sinewave by 180 it would look the same if you phase retarded it by 180.